# How are electrodes working? (EEG)

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

How do electrodes receive signals from the brain when using/doing an EEG? Is there some "circuit" for it? Is it harmful if you have many (more than 50-100) on your head?

I found out that there are small disks used as electrodes to pick up the brain waves. What I didn't understand was how the circuit behind that worked. I mean each electrode has to have an individual circuit, right?

Comment: command to bump question

Comment: Welcome. What did you find out when you researched this question and what didn’t you understand? There is a lot of information about how EEGs work online.

Comment: Also please don't bump questions with meaningless edits.

Comment: I found out that there are small disks used as electrodes to pick up the brain waves. What I didn't understand was how the circuit behind that worked. I mean each electrode has to have an individual circuit, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit is typically made with one or more "ground" wires for EEG, though it's possible to use other EEG contacts as references (more often this is done virtually - [the original recordings are made and digitized with a common ground, and later an average reference](https://eeglab.org/tutorials/ConceptsGuide/rereferencing_background.html) or Laplacian is used to isolate more local signals).

EEG measures extremely weak signals and doesn't have any impact on brain activity itself, any more than listening to the radio impacts the broadcast tower.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any schematic for the circuit?

Comment: @Jakob An op-amp in your recording equipment with one wire to each EEG contacts and one to the ground wire.